TI Lab Cradle for TI nspire CXII communicate protocol
I am working on a device similar to the TI Lab Cradle. Does anyone know the protocol for communication between it and the TI-Nspire CX device? I've analyzed the insertion and removal of Vernier sensors, and each time the USB communication data seems to be different. I don't understand why. I want to analyze the approximate data protocol. Does anyone have information on this?
I need some tips about this.
